# alight vs drop me off vs drop me at

Tags: grammar, difference

which one is correct and why

- please **alight** me at the school, driver.
- please **drop me off** at the school, driver.
- please **drop me** at the school, driver.

Answer (score 1):

One is wrong; two are correct. A passenger alights from (gets out of) a conveyance; the driver drops, or drops off, a passenger.

> alight verb  old-fashioned alight verb (GET OUT OF) ​ to get out of a
>   vehicle, especially a train or bus:
>
> The suspect alighted from the train at Euston and proceeded to
>   Heathrow.
>
> [Alight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alight)
>
> drop verb (TAKE) to take someone to a particular
>   place, usually in a car, and leave them there:
>
> They dropped me off at the main entrance. I dropped him at the library
>   and went shopping.
>
> [Drop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop)

Answer (score 1):

> please alight me at the school, driver.

Alighting is what you do when you are dropped off. You are leaving or exiting the vehicle. This one is definitely incorrect. "Alighting" is something you do, not what someone does to you or for you.

> please drop me at the school, driver.

This is passable. I believe it is correct grammatically.

> please drop me off at the school, driver

This one is correct, and it sounds most natural to me. I would prefer this to the second option, but either of the two will suffice.

Comment: I'd also suggest that the OP avoid referring to the driver as 'driver' unless he's wearing a top hat and monocle. If the OP knows his name say "please drop me at the school, [name of driver]". If he doesn't, say "could you drop me at the school, please".